# Adding a link to a typed.js string

Tags: javascript, typed.js

I'm super new to javascript. I'm using the [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) library, and I would like to add links to my strings. I've thought about changing the strings to html text so I can add links with the `<a>` tag, but I want to keep the type pausing feature the library has, and that has to be done on script (afaik).

so, currently my code is something like this:

```
    <script src="typed.js"></script>
        <script>
            var typed = new Typed('.typedtext', {
                strings: ["random text 1 with ^200 some pauses ^700 in between",
                    "random ^200 text 2 with some pauses in between",
                    "random text ^20 3 with some pauses ^200 in between",],
                typeSpeed: 75,
                backSpeed: 65,
                backDelay: 700,
                smartBackspace: true });
        </script>
```

if i want to add a link on string 3 ("random text ^20 3 with some pauses ^200 in between"), how can i do it?

Comment: Did you try putting an `<a>` tag in your string.

Comment: Should work...[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lcr8npe/)

Comment: thank you guys the <a> tag worked inside the strings when i wrote them between apostrophes '' instead of quotations marks ""